# Copying Sales Person From one Customer to Another

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to copy the Default sales person from the parent account to the current customer when the parent account is updated.  For some reason, the sales person records are being duplicated.  So, I select a Parent Account on the Billing Settings tab then, on the SalesPersons tab, there are two duplicate salespersons that were copied from the parent account.  The parent account only has one sales person on it.  When I save the customer, I get an error, of course:

"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'CustSalesPeople_PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CustSalesPeople'"

I put a breakpoint in my code to confirm that it is only being ran one time.  Any ideas on why this is happening?

TIA!

```
public class CustomerMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerMaint>
{

    public PXSelect<CustSalesPeople, Where<CustSalesPeople.bAccountID, 
        Equal<Current<Customer.parentBAccountID>>>> ParentSalesPeople;

    #region Event Handlers
    protected virtual void Customer_ParentBAccountID_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row == null)
            return;

        Customer cust = (Customer)e.Row;

        if ((e.OldValue == null) || ((int?)e.OldValue != cust.ParentBAccountID))
        {

            if (cust.ParentBAccountID > 0)
            {

                foreach (CustSalesPeople salesPerson in ParentSalesPeople.Select())
                {
                    if (salesPerson.IsDefault == true)
                    {
                        CustSalesPeople sp = Base.SalesPersons.Insert();
                        sp.BAccountID = cust.BAccountID;
                        sp.CommisionPct = salesPerson.CommisionPct;
                        sp.IsDefault = true;
                        sp.LocationID = salesPerson.LocationID;
                        sp.SalesPersonID = salesPerson.SalesPersonID;
                        sp = Base.SalesPersons.Update(sp);
                        //sender.PersistUpdated(sp);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }


    }
   #endregion
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would hit here.

First, as the error message states, you may be inserting a duplicate salesperson record. I would check to see if it exists in the database first.

This may be also due to the fact that the salesperson is attached to the customer location. You are attaching it to a locationID of the parent's location. You might want to search for the matching locationCD for the customer (ex. MAIN) and use that key to update the salesperson, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I have verified that the sales person is not in the database already for the customer.  They are not showing on the Salesperson tab on the Customer screen.  I updated the code to change sp.LocationID = salesPerson.LocationID to sp.LocationID = cust.DefLocationID but, I'm getting "AR Error: This Sales Person is added for all the Customer locations already."  I'm on version 19.111.0038 now.